# Nested for loop in python, Can't seem to get it working

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to insert a string from one list into another list on a string match (list are different lengths) I can't seem to figure out how to get in working. So i loop over both list, on a string match i insert the next line from list2 into list1 and this needs to continue until all lines from list 2 are inserted in the right place in list1. This is the code i have right now.

```
with open('D:\\TranslateFIles\\Ext_Python.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    list1 = f.readlines()
f.close()

with open('D:\\TranslateFIles\\Combo_Python.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    list2 = f.readlines()
f.close()

outFile=open('D:\\TranslateFIles\\Output3_Python.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

list3 = list1.copy()


for element, i in enumerate(list3):
        for j,b in zip(list2, list2[1:]):
            if i == j: 
                list3.insert(element, b)
                print(*list3) 
            
for line in list3:
    outFile.write(line) 
outFile.close()
```

This is the output i get right now .

```
T14-P2818-L30:Location
**T14-P8629-A2067-L999:Vestiging**
T14-P8629-A1033-L999:Location
T14-P8629-A2060-L999:Magasin
T14-P4960-V1000-P2818-L128:TransferRoute
T14-P4960-V1003-P2818-L128:WhseEmployee
T14-P4960-V1004-P2818-L128:WorkCenter
T14-P4960-V1001-P2818-L128:StockkeepingUnit
T14-P4960-X1-L999:
T14-F1-P2818-L128:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A1033-L999:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A2060-L999:Code
T14-F2-P2818-L128:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A2060-L999:Nom
T14-F130-P2818-L128:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A1033-L999:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A2060-L999:Code emplacement par d‚faut
```

This is the output i want to get.

```
T14-P2818-L30:Location
T14-P8629-A1033-L999:Location
T14-P8629-A2060-L999:Magasin
**T14-P8629-A2067-L999:Vestiging**
T14-P4960-V1000-P2818-L128:TransferRoute
T14-P4960-V1003-P2818-L128:WhseEmployee
T14-P4960-V1004-P2818-L128:WorkCenter
T14-P4960-V1001-P2818-L128:StockkeepingUnit
T14-P4960-X1-L999:
T14-F1-P2818-L128:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A1033-L999:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A2060-L999:Code
**T14-F1-P8629-A2067-L999:Code**
T14-F2-P2818-L128:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A2060-L999:Nom
**T14-F2-P8629-A2067-L999:Naam**
T14-F130-P2818-L128:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A1033-L999:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A2060-L999:Code emplacement par d‚faut
**T14-F130-P8629-A2067-L999:Standaard opslaglocatiecode**
```

Items in list one

```
T14-P2818-L30:Location
T14-P8629-A1033-L999:Location
T14-P8629-A2060-L999:Magasin
T14-P4960-V1000-P2818-L128:TransferRoute
T14-P4960-V1003-P2818-L128:WhseEmployee
T14-P4960-V1004-P2818-L128:WorkCenter
T14-P4960-V1001-P2818-L128:StockkeepingUnit
T14-P4960-X1-L999:
T14-F1-P2818-L128:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A1033-L999:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A2060-L999:Code
T14-F2-P2818-L128:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A2060-L999:Nom
T14-F130-P2818-L128:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A1033-L999:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A2060-L999:Code emplacement par d‚faut
T14-F5700-P2818-L128:Name 2
T14-F5700-P8629-A1033-L999:Name 2
T14-F5700-P8629-A2060-L999:Nom 2
T14-F5701-P2818-L128:Address
T14-F5701-P8629-A1033-L999:Address
T14-F5701-P8629-A2060-L999:Adresse
T14-F5702-P2818-L128:Address 2
T14-F5702-P8629-A1033-L999:Address 2
T14-F5702-P8629-A2060-L999:Adresse (2Šme ligne)
T14-F5703-P2818-L128:City
T14-F5703-P8629-A1033-L999:City
T14-F5703-P8629-A2060-L999:Ville
T14-F5704-P2818-L128:Phone No.
```

Items in list two

```
T14-P8629-A1033-L999:Location
T14-P8629-A2067-L999:Location
T14-F1-P8629-A1033-L999:Code
T14-F1-P8629-A2067-L999:Code
T14-F2-P8629-A1033-L999:Name
T14-F2-P8629-A2067-L999:Name
T14-F130-P8629-A1033-L999:Default Bin Code
T14-F130-P8629-A2067-L999:Default Bin Code
T14-F5700-P8629-A1033-L999:Name 2
T14-F5700-P8629-A2067-L999:Name 2
T14-F5701-P8629-A1033-L999:Address
T14-F5701-P8629-A2067-L999:Address
T14-F5702-P8629-A1033-L999:Address 2
T14-F5702-P8629-A2067-L999:Address 2
T14-F5703-P8629-A1033-L999:City
T14-F5703-P8629-A2067-L999:City
T14-F5704-P8629-A1033-L999:Phone No.
T14-F5704-P8629-A2067-L999:Phone No.
T14-F5705-P8629-A1033-L999:Phone No. 2
T14-F5705-P8629-A2067-L999:Phone No. 2
T14-F5706-P8629-A1033-L999:Telex No.
T14-F5706-P8629-A2067-L999:Telex No.
T14-F5707-P8629-A1033-L999:Fax No.
T14-F5707-P8629-A2067-L999:Fax No.
T14-F5713-P8629-A1033-L999:Contact
T14-F5713-P8629-A2067-L999:Contact
T14-F5714-P8629-A1033-L999:Post Code
T14-F5714-P8629-A2067-L999:Post Code
T14-F5715-P8629-A1033-L999:County
T14-F5715-P8629-A2067-L999:County
```

The string with A2067 should be in Dutch, but i'm still translating.

Comment: please provide sample of `list1` and `list2`, `with open('D:\\Tr...` does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to insert in `l3` (which is a copy of `l1`) an element from `l2` only if that element from `l2` is identical to the next element from `l2`? If so, try:

```py
import more_itertools as mit


l3 = l1.copy()
for i, j in mit.pairwise(l2):
    if i == j:
        l3.append(i)
```

My solution is based on `pairwise` function from `more_itertools`. `pairwise` iterates on every pair of subsequent elements in a list.